# identifier "hash_map" is undefined?

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash

I need to use a dictionary that will map pairs of `int`s to a different pair of `int`s. Other SO questions on the topic claim that C++ has `std::map` and a `hash_map`, but for some reason my code doesn't seem to recognize it.

To try it out, I copied a random code I found:

```
hash_map<const char*, int, hash<const char*>, eqstr> months;
```

Visual Studio claims that: `identifier "hash_map" is undefined`

Any idea what it means, and how I could fix it? It's been a long time since I last used C++ so sorry if the question is basic... thanks.

Comment: "To try it out, I copied a random code I found" – oh yeah, that's not how programming works.

Comment: Hey... what's wrong with that? When I use something for the first time, yeah, I copy some code, play around with it, and when I'm confident enough to use it I write stuff on my own. Is that so bad...? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hash_map` is in the [STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/), an ancient library that formed the basis of the parts of the standard C++ library, but not in the standard library itself.

Since C++11, the standard library has a similar container called `unordered_map`.

Comment: OK... so I tried this: `std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;` and now I get: `std namespace has no member "ordered_map"`. Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: @Cheshie: Did you `#include <unordered_map>`? To learn about the standard library, you'd be better off with a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) or [online reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) rather than trying to compile random bits of code of dubious origin.

Comment: thanks for asking; no, I didn't (*embarrassing!*) :P Thank you! and thanks for the references.